# Adding text to ArcGIS Javascript layer

Tags: labeling, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using the ArcGIS Javascript API (v3.15) for a basic use case of placing some markers with text on a map. I am able to add the marker, but I am running into issues inserting text on that marker.

Here is my code:

```
require([
  "esri/map",
  "esri/dijit/BasemapToggle",
  "esri/dijit/LocateButton",
  "esri/geometry/Point",
  "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", 
  "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol", 
  "esri/symbols/Font",
  "esri/symbols/TextSymbol", 
  "esri/Color",
  "esri/graphic", 
  "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(
  Map, BasemapToggle, LocateButton, Point, SimpleMarkerSymbol, Font, TextSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, Color, Graphic, GraphicsLayer
) {
  map = new Map("map", {
    center: [mapval[0][2],mapval[0][1]],
    zoom: 18,
    basemap: "streets"
  });

  map.on("load", function() {
    var gl = new GraphicsLayer();
    var font = new Font("20px", Font.STYLE_NORMAL, Font.VARIANT_NORMAL, Font.WEIGHT_BOLDER);
    for (var i = 0; i < mapval.length; i++){
      var p = new Point(mapval[i][2], mapval[i][1]);
      var s = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 20,
        new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
        new Color([255,0,0]), 1),
        new Color([0,255,0,0.25]));
      var g = new Graphic(p, s);
      g.setAttributes({
        name: mapval[i][0]
      });
      gl.add(g);

      var t = new TextSymbol(mapval[i][0], font, new Color([0, 0, 0]));
      var g2 = new Graphic(p, t);
      gl.add(g2);
    }

    map.addLayer(gl);                   
  });

  var toggle = new BasemapToggle({
    map: map,
    visible: true,
    basemap: "satellite"
  }, "BasemapToggle");
  toggle.startup();

  var geoLocate = new LocateButton({
    map: map
  }, "LocateButton");
  geoLocate.startup();

});
```

Comment: In your require statement, the *SimpleLineSymbol* variable is in the wrong place. Try moving it between *SimpleMarkerSymbol* and *Font*.

Answer (score 1):

As raykendo pointed out, the require functions were not in the correct order.  Once that was corrected the label was displayed.